# Issue with player landing on moving platform - Infinite Runner

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object

I’m making an infinite runner game and have it set so that the platforms move to the left rather than the player moving forwards. My issue is that I have a platform the loops up and down as it moves left and when my player lands on this specific platform, they start bouncing off the platform, which isn’t what I want.

[Moving Platform GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJn6T.gif)

One way to solve this is by having the player as a child of the platform, which does work and stops the bouncing, but it also means that the player is then moving left along with the platform.

[Moving Platform (Child) GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKSsF.gif)

I know why this is happening as a child object will follow the parent object, but I can’t find a way to have my player act to not move with the platform without the bouncing issue.

The player has a rigidbody and box collider attached, the moving player only has a box collider.

Player jumping script:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    player_RB.velocity = new Vector2(player_RB.velocity.x, 20);
}
```

Moving platform script:

```
private int moveVertical;

void Start()
{
    moveVertical = Random.Range(1, 3);
}

void Update()
{
    transform.position -= transform.right * (Time.deltaTime * 7);

    if (transform.position.x <= -20)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    if (transform.position.y < -2f)
    {
        moveVertical = 1;
    }
    else if (transform.position.y > 2f)
    {
        moveVertical = 2;
    }

    if (moveVertical == 1)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else if (moveVertical == 2)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 5 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Can anyone offer a solution to this? I just want the player to land on the moving platform normally without bouncing or moving to the left with the platform.

- UPDATE -

Still having no luck with this, although appreciate the suggestions so far @LewdAngel. I've created and provided a link to a test project, would be grateful if someone can have a look and see if they can sort this issue. Figured it maybe easier to look into this with a project as perhaps the way I've set up the project means the other suggestions wouldn't work.

[Test Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PBNRoQ5YZUhgi5xFlqmFOS6eByl7CSev/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new Physics Material and set its Bounciness to **0**, and Bounce Combine to **minimum**. Then apply the material to your platform prefab or manually to all platforms. It should prevent the bouncy behavior.

As for moving together with a platform, just revert to your previous implementation where Player wasn't a child object.

[Physic Material in Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Cheers for the suggestions, i should have mentioned that i have already created a physics material and set the bounciness to 0 but this hasn't worked.

Also, I am able to remove the child behaviour from the player when they leave the platform. Reason i'm using the child method as it's the one way i can find that prevents the player from bouncing on the platform, but with this i get the issue of moving with the platform which i can't fix.

Comment: Assuming that you've already tried to change [bounce threshold](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics-bounceThreshold.html).
You can also try to set your vertical velocity to 0 when you touch the platform. You can do this by sticking [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) onto your player and overwriting the vertical velocity when a collision happens with the platform which you'll probably want to tag with a tag or empty component.

Comment: Hmm, thats not working for me either. I've realised after testing that the 'bouncing' effect occurs when you land on the platform when it's moving downwards. I've confirmed this by just having a platform move only move back and forth on the Y axis and the player only bounces on the way down. I've tried changing the platform movement to MoveTowards, AddForce and still no luck.

Comment: Check this version of your Test Project [GDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZU2oSrBjZ_Xph9OPkbJhK-_v2iVj4QIW/view?usp=sharing)
It's a variant which you had already tried, with parenting player to a platform, but I've moved horizontal movement from platforms to the player and this allowed to achieve both sticky behavior on vertically moving surfaces while retaining freedom of movement. You can achieve this without parenting but you'll have to sync vertical movements of the player and a platform, otherwise, the moment a platform will move down gravity won't move the player down in time.

Comment: Cheers mate, appreciate you taking the time to look in to this. Your project is different to my one as you said, but it looks promising and works great, so it should be something i can apply to mine. Thanks again.